# Webkit2gtk get new window link

Tags: webkit, webkitgtk, webkit2

I need to get the link in a new window requirement webkit2gtk

[Where is the uri of the new window, in create-web-view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127970/where-is-the-uri-of-the-new-window-in-create-web-view)

its to webkitGTK i need for webkit2Gtk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to the [`create` signal](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebView.html#WebKitWebView-create).
Then, you can get the [request from the NavigationAction](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitNavigationAction.html#webkit-navigation-action-get-request) and from the request, [you can get the uri](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitURIRequest.html#webkit-uri-request-get-uri).